# What is the smallest dimension that allows finding $n$ points at distances $|x_i-x_j|^{\delta/2}$, where $0<\delta<1$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

Let $x_1,\cdots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$, are there $\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_n \in \mathbb{R}^s$, such that 
$|x_i-x_j|^{\delta}=||\xi_i-\xi_j||^2$,  $0<\delta<1$, what is the smallest $s$ to guarantee the existence of $\xi_i$s for any $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I’m afraid that $s=n$, if it exists. You determine the Gram matrix of the $\xi_i$. If you are sure it  will be positive semi-definite, then in most cases it will be positive definite, which yields linear independence of the $\xi_i$.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I am sure it exists as $|x_i-x_j|^\delta$ is conditionally positive definite. Why is $s=O(n)$? I was thinking it should be $O(n^2)$

Comment: If the resulting matrix is positive definite, then you may define the scalar product by that matrix. The same, with some work, holds for the degenerate case. So, if the $\xi_i$ exist, then they exist in $\mathbb R^n$.